# Reputação mostrada errada no chat

Tags: bug, status-intencional

No chat Estouro de Pilha está sendo mostrada minha reputação como 38, sendo que o meu total é 36.

Era pra eu estar com 38 se não tivesse recebido uma avaliação negativa(-2) em uma pergunta que fiz... Sou só eu que estou vendo errado?

Answer (score 4):

O chat mostra a pontuação geral em todos os sites da rede Stack Exchange.

Olhe no [seu perfil](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13538/flemos) e verá que tem dois pontos em outros sites.

Comment: obrigado @utluiz, não sabia..

Comment: @flemos Estamos às ordens. Sempre que tiver dúvidas sobre o site pode abrir uma pergunta no meta ou acessar o [chat].

Comment: Tens certeza? Aqui só mostra a pontuação do SOpt.

Comment: @Patrick Que coisa! Você é o único que o chat mostrou apenas a pontuação do SOpt. O resto que testei apareceu a soma de todos. Uai, sô! Que magia negra é essa?

Comment: @utluiz Eu também apenas vejo a pontuação do SOpt.

Comment: Eu acredito que a regra é que no chat se mostra a soma de todos os sites que possui pelo menos 200 de reputação, assim como no flair. No caso do OP, houve um delay ao mostrar a reputação dele que era 38 e caiu para 36 ao receber um voto negativo. Coincidentemente ele tinha 2 pontos em outros sites, que gerou a confusão.

Comment: @Math Segundo [esta resposta do meta principal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77716/total-reputation-is-different-in-chat-and-flair/77718#77718), a pontuação deveria ser a soma. Só não sei porque não funciona para alguns usuários.

Comment: @utluiz você tem razão, mas talvez pela resposta já ter 3 anos é possível que ela esteja desatualizada e a regra tenha mudado nesse meio tempo. Entretanto não achei nada que comprove isso.